# The argument type 'MyUser? Function(User)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MyUser Function(User?)'. Flutter Firebase App Build Problem

Tags: firebase, flutter

About flutter firebase app build.
Stream function got a red line. Currently using 2 files auth.dart and user.dart

MY CODE
auth.dart file :

```
import 'package:coffee_dan/models/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  MyUser Function(User? event)? get userFromFirebaseUser => null;

  MyUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User user) {
    // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
    return user!= null ? MyUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<MyUser> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);  Red Line in here **_userFromFirebaseUser**
  }

  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And

user.dart File :

```
class MyUser {
  final String uid;
  MyUser({required this.uid});
}
```

**Initial code**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBYPF.png)
**Updated code**
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrxTQ.png)

Comment: `_userFromFirebaseUser` can't return null. Its return type needs to be non-nullable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 things to change in your code:

1. Your _userFromFirebaseUser signature needs to receive a nullable User, you will be able then to remove your "ignore" comment line. It should look as follows:

   ```
   MyUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
     return user != null ? MyUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
   }
   ```
2. Your user getter should return Stream<MyUser?> and that will get rid of the error. That one should look as below:

   ```
   Stream<MyUser?> get user {
     return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
   }
   ```

**Full code (keep your imports):**

```
class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  MyUser Function(User? event)? get userFromFirebaseUser => null;

  MyUser? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    return user!= null ? MyUser(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<MyUser?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ummm, I think I have made it worse.It's getting 5 errors now.

Comment: You can edit your initial question and add attachments there. And write Update 1, Update 2 and so on.

Comment: I still see the same original code. I will edit my response with the full class code, I tested it and it works.

Comment: There are 2 img and can u send me a screenshot

Comment: You have an additional closing curly brace in the line 11. Just delete it and should work. Or copy the class from my response :)

Comment: My bad, ''O WOW'' it Works,                                                                                        
   Thanks  yr awesome

Comment: Happy to help :)